# Upload a csv file, import and process in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm currently importing CSV files into my database like so:

```
class InventoryItemsController < ApplicationController

def import
    InventoryItem.import(params[:file], params[:store_id])
    redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path, notice: "Inventory Imported."
end

end
```

Model method.

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.import(file, store_id)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_upc_and_store_id(row[0], store_id)
    inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => row.to_hash["price"], :updated_at => "#{Time.now}")
end

end
```

The problem is that I'm now beginning to do some larger csv files (65k rows) and the app just hangs there for 10 minutes while everything runs. Is there a way I can upload the file and then process it in the background? Running Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem? It allows you to queue jobs in the database, and then process it asynchronously in the background.

Quick description from the delayed_job README page on github:

> Delayed::Job (or DJ) encapsulates the common pattern of asynchronously executing longer tasks in the background.

## Edit: Also look at sidekiq

Another good option is sidekiq. You can see how these different asynch processing gems all compare by reading the [sidekiq FAQ](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ). The [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq) is a bit old, but it still gives a good tutorial and introduction on how to use sidekiq.

Comment: This looks like exactly the thing. Having some trouble implementing it though. If you're savvy with `delayed_job` and want to see my related question, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140914/delayed-job-undefined-method-error-when-using-handle-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You can try [FastCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) instead of CSV class.

Comment: `Ruby 1.9` has adopted `FasterCSV` as its built-in `CSV` library.