# delayed_job: 'undefined method' error when using handle_asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, delayed-job

I'm attempting to use delayed_job to run a larger csv import into my rails database. Here are my controller and model methods:

controller method

```
def import
    InventoryItem.import(params[:file], params[:store_id])
    redirect_to vendors_dashboard_path, notice: "Inventory Imported."
end
```

model method

```
def self.import(file, store_id)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_upc_and_store_id(row[0], store_id)
inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => row.to_hash["price"], :updated_at => "#{Time.now}")
    end
end

handle_asynchronously :import
```

I've added 'delayed_job' and 'daemons' to my gemfile, then bundled. Ran the generator, started a development worker process with `rake jobs:work`, and then tried to run an import through the app. Here's the error I get:

```
Routing Error
undefined method `import' for class `InventoryItem'
```

Did I miss something when integrating delayed_job? This import process ran fine prior, so just wondering where I've messed up. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

Your import is a class method, you should call handle_asynchronously on your model class name's singleton class:

You can use the metaclass trick to alias class methods:

```
class << self
   def import(file, store_id)
     CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      inventory_item = InventoryItem.find_or_initialize_by_upc_and_store_id(row[0], store_id)
      inventory_item.update_attributes(:price => row.to_hash["price"], :updated_at => "#{Time.now}")
     end
   end
  handle_asynchronously :import
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I wrap my import method in the above alias, within `inventory_item.rb`? I'm getting a `NoMethod Error in InventoryItemsController#import` error now, pointing to the line calling `import` on `InventoryItem`. Thoughts?

Comment: @settheline I think the error you experienced is due to not having removed the "self." in front of the method definition after encapsulating it in "class << self".  For clarity, here is an example:

def self.import
  do stuff
end

Becomes

class << self
  def import
     do stuff
  end
  handle_asynchronously :import
end